# Из списка смежных вершин в матрицу инцидентности

Tags: pascal, графы

Подскажите пожалуйста в следующем вопросе. 
Мне необходимо получить матрицу инцидентности из списка смежных вершин. Искал долго и упорно, но найти ответ так и не смог. Понятие, что такое матрица инцидентности и список смежных вершин есть, но переход от одного к другому застал меня в ступор.Как это сделать можно? Очень хотелось бы, чтобы была подсказка , как реализовать на Pascal ABC .
Пожалуйста помогите !!!

Answer (score 0):

Поставьте единицы в те ячейки i-й строки таблицы, номера которых которых присутствуют в списке смежности для i-го элемента. Собственно, больше и говорить тут нечего.

Comment: не совсем понятно

Comment: Что непонятно ?

Comment: как это реализовать на паскале

Comment: Почитать о массивах. Таблица - двумерный массив.